# How do I "SPLASH_TIME" stop after clicking button?

Tags: java, android

I have a video running on "RAW"

Clicking the button goes to the next activity, but "SPLASH_TIME" is still counting.

```
''Button btn_1; VideoView videoView2;
```

`private static int SPLASH_TIME = 10000; // This is 10 seconds`

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
            setContentView (R.layout.activity_pub2);

        btn_1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.line1);
        btn_1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Toast.makeText (Pub2.this, "BOOOOAAAAAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
                Intent orderDetail = new Intent (Pub2.this, Main2.class);
                startActivity (orderDetail);
            }
        });
```

```
videoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById (R.id.videoView2);
videoView2.setVideoURI (Uri.parse ("android.resource: //" + getPackageName () + "/" + R.raw.crop));
```

```
videoView2.requestFocus ();
```

```
videoView2.start ();
```

```
new Handler (). postDelayed (new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                // Do any action here. Now we are moving to next page
                Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent (Pub2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity (mySuperIntent);
                finish ();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME);
```

I can stay in the new activity but after "SPLASH_TIME" finishes SPLASH_TIME = 10000;
Interrupts and goes to the Intent given to it

```
Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent (Pub2.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity (mySuperIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent (Pub2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity (mySuperIntent);
                finish ();
    }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, Mark is as accepted, if it is useful and correct

Answer (score 0):

Stop your handler by calling `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`. It will remove all callBacks from handler. Define a Handler in your class

```
 Handler mHandler= newHandler();
    void foo(){
    mHandler.postDelayed (new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                // Do any action here. Now we are moving to next page
                Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent (Pub2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity (mySuperIntent);
                finish ();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME);
    }

   @Override onStop(){
       super.onStop();
       handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
   }
```